# jetty-maven-plugin with run-war stops the maven execution

Tags: java, maven, embedded-jetty

I want to use jetty-maven-plugin as a platform where i can test my applications with external assambled wars.

So i set up my maven-jetty-plugin with following configuration:

```
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>

                           <war>${project.build.directory}/some.war</war>

                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>start-jetty</id>
                                <phase>integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run-war</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                           <war>${project.build.directory}/some.war</war>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>stop</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <stopKey>stop</stopKey>
                                    <stopPort>8888</stopPort>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
```

And when i run it i get something like that:

```
[INFO] Started ServerConnector@55b0e42e{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8888}
[INFO] Started @21213ms
[INFO] Started Jetty Server
```

Which is ok, but it stops the execution. After that my tests should run but it doesn't. I can use **jetty:start** which will be a workaround without war as it proceed the test execution, but i can't attach the war file to this goal.

Answer (score 0):

That's how the maven plugin is designed.

Its not meant for external wars, or multiple wars, or multiple contexts, or production use.

It's designed to operate on a single project (which can be part of a maven multi-module reactor build), which is defined as `<packaging>war</packaging>`.

Only the `jetty:start` allows execution to continue, all other goals are not designed for that.

`jetty:start` is designed to work with the `integration-test` phase of maven, and the `maven-failsafe-plugin`.

See: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html#Using_jetty_and_maven-failsafe-plugin

All other `maven-jetty-plugin` goals are designed for manual testing of the project with `<packaging>war</packaging>`